Is there a complex version of Straightened theorem for vector fields
The real case’s straightened theorem Straightened theorem for vector fields or in John Lee’s book “Introduction to smooth manifold” Chapter 9, so-called “Canonical forms for commuting vector fields”, is to transform a given smooth field $V$ at a point locally to a smooth coordinate frame, namely $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.
I wonder if there’s a similar result in complex manifold, changing conditions of “smooth vector field $V$” to a “holomorphic vector field $V$”, and such existence of holomorphic coordinates instead of just smooth coordinates.

Did you try to repeat the real proof in the complex setting?

If you mean by the proof in Wiki, I have tried to imitate, and maybe the only difference occurs in holomorphic dependence of the ODE solution to the coefficients and initial conditions, so I believe it’s right.

Yes. For holomorphic ODEs you can check, for instance, Hille's book "ODEs in complex domain".
